# How quickly can I kill weeds by covering them?

Tags: weed-control

I want to plant some seeds soon and have a load of creeping charlie in my garden beds.  If I throw down a tarp, about how long would it take for the weeds to be completely killed?  Would laying down landscape (weed) fabric temporarily work as quickly?

Or is there a better strategy that doesn't involve attempting to pull them all by hand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should not take long. It depends on temperature. If the temperature is in the 80's, it takes a week to 10 days to thoroughly do the job.

Use black plastic. It absorbs heat and cooks and kills the weeds and their seeds underneath.

Comment: Have you done this before?  General guidelines would be great--say it's 70 degrees and sunny.  Maybe I'll unroll a bunch of garbage bags.

Comment: Yes.  If the temperature is in the 80's, it takes a week to 10 days to thoroughly do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I've used flattened cardboard boxes layered and weighed down by bricks before.  *It takes 3 wks to 2 months* to kill everything underneath.  At the end, cardboard has black and white mold on bottom so you can throw it away or layer mulch on top and let it naturally erode.